# Back button label

Tags: gui-design, labels, back-button

What should be the label written next to a back button? Should it be the current activity or the activity the button would take us to?
Take facebook's mobile website for an example-
[image: Facebook mobile website associated with clicking on show all groups button]

The label says, "All Groups" which is the current activity/display.
I think that the label should say which activity it is going to point because it is just next to the back button and the user might take it as the activity back button is referring to. So, instead the label should be "All Bookmarks" or something.

Please answer to a general context and not only to this example.

Answer (score 1):

It should definitely say the "destination activity". Also, the back button should take the user one step back so that they arrive at where they came from immediately prior. To most users, back means "**go back one step**" not "go back 3 steps" or "go back 5 steps".

Answer (score 0):

I also think that it should tell you where it will take you. Depending on how much space you have, ideally you can get "Back" in there as well.

e.g. "<- Back to All Groups"

Just be careful when it's possible to get to that site, without coming from the previous one (like when Google sends a user directly to a subpage). In this case the "Back" can be misleading, because he never was on the previous site.

Comment: I think 'back to' is unnecessary and button followed by the label is enough, especially for mobile.

Comment: Just to point that 'All Groups' is the current activity and 'All Bookmarks' is the previous one